# why not use _xxx change readonly property?

Tags: ios

I declare a readonly property in .h file

`@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *itemsArray;`

I implement getter method in .m file

`- (NSArray *)itemsArray {
    return [[self dataArray] copy];
}`

Now,I can't use _itemsArray change it,why is that?And if i did't implement getter method,i can use _itemsArray to change it.
[image]

Comment: That's the purpose of a (computed) **readonly** property.

Comment: I did't use setter method to change it,If I did't implement getter method manually,_itemsArray = self.dataArray no error ,why is that?

Comment: To set a computed readonly property is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've implemented *all required accessors* for your property (getter in case of readonly property). In this case an underscore ivar is not automatically synthesized.

Comment: Thank you,I got it.

Answer (score 0):

In short you can't change your value or you can't apply **setter** method with `readonly` property.

Comment: If I did't implement getter method manually,`_itemsArray = self.dataArray` no error

Answer (score 0):

I think that the readonly property do not implement setter method, so that the iVar of itemsArray property mapping is not created. On the other hand, this property mapped name of iVar to be undefined. If you want to use ‘_itemsArray’ as iVar name of the property. After You write  *'@synthesize itemsArray = _itemsArray;'* statement into .m file. No error occurred.